# How to only iterate certain positions in the Itertool combinations

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I am working on a python project which iterates through all the possible combinations of entries in a row of excel data to find which combination produces the correct output.

To achieve this, I am iterating through different combinations of 0 and 1 to choose whether that entry is required for the combination. 1 meaning data point is included in the calculation and 0 meaning the data point is not included.

The number of combinations would thus be equal to 2 ^ (Number of excel columns)

**Example Excel Data:**
1, 22, 7, 11, 2, 4

**Example Iteration:**
(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)

I could be looking for what combination of the excel data would result in an output of 3, the only correct combination of the excel data being the above iteration.

However, I would know that any value greater than 3 would not be included in a possible combination that would equal 3. As such I would like to choose and set the values of these columns to 0 and iterate the other columns only. This would in turn reduce the number of combinations.
Combination = 2 ^ (Number of excel columns - Fixed Entry Columns)

At the moment I am using Itertools.products to get all combination which I need:

```
Numbers = ["0","1"]

for item in itertools.product(Numbers, repeat=len(df.columns)):

    Iteration = pd.DataFrame(item) # Iteration e.g (0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
    
    Data = df.iloc[0] # Excel data row
    
    Data = Data.to_numpy()
    Iteration  = Iteration.astype(float)
    
    Answer = np.dot(Data, Iteration) # Get the result of (Iteration * Data) to check if answer is correct
```

This results in iterating through combinations which I know will not work.
Is there a way to only iterate 0's and 1's in certain positions of the combination while keeping the known entries a fixed value (either 0 or 1) to reduce the possible combinations?

There are some excel files have over 25 columns which as a result would be 33,554,432 combinations. As such I am trying to reduce the number of columns which I need to iterate by setting values to the columns that I do know.

If you would need further clarification please let me know. I am novice programmer so I may be overlooking or over complicating a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Find which columns meet your criteria for exclusion.  Then just get the product combinations for the other columns.

One possible method:

```
from itertools import product

LIMIT=10
column_data = [1, 22, 7, 11, 2, 4]

changeable_indexes = [i for i,x in enumerate(column_data) if x <= LIMIT]

for item in product([0,1], repeat=len(changeable_indexes)):
    row_iteration = [0] * len(column_data)
    for index, value in zip(changeable_indexes, item):
        row_iteration[index]  = value
    print(row_iteration)
```